# Unable to send the Cordova plugin result

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm new to Cordova and I'm training to send the result after dismissedViewController and I'm passing variable to Plugin class

```
- (void)coolMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*) mycommand
{
    _callbackId=mycommand.callbackId; //here im saving plugin id
    NSDictionary* myarg = [mycommand.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    LiveViewController *viewController = [[LiveViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LiveViewController" bundle:nil];

    viewController.openTokApi_Key = [[myarg safeObjectForKey:@"apiKey"] stringValue];

    viewController.openTokSessionID = [myarg safeObjectForKey:@"liveSessionId"];

    viewController.openTokToken = [myarg safeObjectForKey:@"tokenId"];

    viewController.hybridParams = myarg;

    [self.viewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES  completion:nil];
}
```

After completing my task I dismissedViewController and I created instance for this call and called below method

```
-(void)result:(NSString *)success
{

CDVPluginResult* pluginResult=[CDVPluginResult 
  resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"ok"];

  [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:_callbackId];

}
```

However, I'm not able to get this result in my JS.

Comment: Can you explain the part of "and i created intance for this call and called bellow method"?

Comment: Above two methods i placed in Plugin class and first method will call automatically when the plugin called and next method Im calling from view Controller for that I created object(instance) based on object i'm calling second method(result) and i'm passing callBackId of plugin

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Still not clear, better share that code too

Comment: @jcesarmobile can you please see this code https://github.com/jaibharathreddy/cordova-ios-tokbox